# Can left-hand and right-hand circular polarizations exist at the same time?

Tags: circular-polarization

I read [in a comment](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/long-range-hf-polarization/16883?noredirect=1#comment27630_16883):

> it doesn't matter which circular polarization you choose, because they are both present, and the whole point here is to select one of them instead of receiving both and getting mixing.

The premise of the point being made seems to be that an HF signal received after making a pass or passes through the ionosphere will be *both* left-hand and right-hand circularly polarized, and so a receiving antenna of either chirality will not be subject to fading as a linearly polarized antenna would be.

Is this possible, for a signal to be *both* left- and right-hand polarized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible, for a signal to be both left- and right-hand polarized?

Yes, it's very much possible:

While the superposition of two orthogonal circular polarizations might¹ indeed look linear (just as the superposition of a horizontal and a vertical polarized wave at appropriate phasing is a circularly polarized wave), of course that means that a linearly polarized wave is at the same time circularly polarized in both directions.

Technically, this is widely exploited: Satellite receivers use polarization multiplex. That is awesome, because you get two totally independently useful "subchannels", as long all media the wave travels through is a largely a linear medium and isotropic. (And the microwave frequencies geostationary satellite downlink channel fulfills that pretty well.)

Even if that's not the case, you still get *some* isolation between RHCP and LHCP, and can use that for MIMO techniques to increase your data rate or robustness beyond what you can do on a single polarization.

---

¹ might because that's not necessarily the case. Remember the Poincaré sphere:

[image: 2128506 / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0]

When you add waves of different polarizations, you wander on the surface of that sphere; only when you add RHCP and LHCP with the same magnitude, you end up with a linear polarization. The angle of that is then defined by the phase between the two constituent waves; every other combination, every attenuation that affects one rotational sense more than the other, will produce an elliptic polarization.

Let me rephrase your question:

> Is this possible, for a *wave* to be both left- and right-hand polarized at the same time?

No, that's not possible, because any wave can only occupy **one** point in polarization space.

Comment: That's a good point about the distinction between _wave_ and _signal_. I probably should have used _wave_ in my question as it was closer to the point: the application under consideration was amateurs on HF, where almost certainly no one is doing any MIMO.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II but people are using polarization multiplex, aren't they?

Comment: People yes. But hams? Not much that I know of, especially on HF.

Comment: Interesting! Sure, a linearly polarized HF antenna is large enough to be cumbersome, adding a phased second element of orthogonal polarization doesn't sound tempting at all, and circularly polarized aperture antennas are mechanically infeasible alltogether.

Comment: There's also the problem of equipment. Very few radios a ham might have even have two antenna inputs. I had to [build my own](https://github.com/bitglue/lpsdr/tree/pi_hat/pi_hat) because the only options I know of are really expensive, like the USRP. And hams are notoriously cheap.

Comment: gotta contradict you on the cheapness, though! I find hams to be pretty invested (financially) in their hobbies. People buy 200€ morse paddles, 2000€ receivers, they drill holes through their car roofs... (apropos GNU Radio: this weekend is [virtual SDRA @HAMRADIO](https://2020.sdra.io/pages/programme.html))

Comment: "as long all media the wave travels through is a largely a linear medium and anisotropic." I think you mean "isotropic" here?

Comment: err yes. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. The electric field vector can only point in one direction at a time, so there's no way it could simultaneously rotate in two directions.

However it is possible to consider any possible polarization as a [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) of left- and right-handed circular polarization.

When there are multiple radiation sources, either because there are multiple transmitters or because the same signal is being received through multiple paths, then the result at the receiver is the addition of each source. Adding two circular polarizations of opposite chirality together produces a linear polarization.

This can be shown graphically as a 3D parametric plot:

[image]
([editable source](https://christopherchudzicki.github.io/MathBox-Demos/parametric_curves_3D.html?settings=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))

On the left in yellow, we have:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x(t) &= \cos(t) \\ 
y(t) &= \sin(t)
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

On the right in blue we have:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x(t) &= -\cos(t) \\ 
y(t) &= \sin(t)
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

And the middle in green is the addition of these two:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x(t) &= \cos(t) - \cos(t) \\ 
y(t) &= \sin(t) + \sin(t)
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

It's pretty plain to see this simplifies to $x(t) = 0$ as the opposite electric fields along the x axis cancel each other.

As the two sources change in relative phase, the plane of the resulting linear polarization rotates:

[image]
([editable source](https://christopherchudzicki.github.io/MathBox-Demos/parametric_curves_3D.html?settings=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))

Here, green is showing

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x(t) &= \cos(t+2) - \cos(t) \\ 
y(t) &= \sin(t+2) + \sin(t)
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

While it's not so immediately obvious to see the cancellation, it remains true that opposite helices like this will cancel each other in *some* plane, as long as they are equal in amplitude.

If the two sources are not equal in amplitude, then the result is elliptical polarization:

[image]
([editable source](https://christopherchudzicki.github.io/MathBox-Demos/parametric_curves_3D.html?settings=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))

It is true that the ionosphere is time-variant, and so at one time the signal as received may be left-handed, and some time later right-handed. But is impossible for it to be *both at the same time*, although one could consider a linear polarization to be the superposition of both circular polarizations in equal amplitude.

The problem is an ionospheric channel does not guarantee equal amplitude. Thus, a circularly polarized receive antenna will still be subject to fading as the signal randomly wanders between left- and right-handed chirality, as well as linear and all the points between (elliptical polarizations).

Comment: ... so in other words *yes, they can exist* and their sum is equivalent to a linear polarization.

Comment: @user253751 Any possible polarization can be represented by the [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) of two orthogonal polarizations of specified amplitude and phase. Vertical and horizontal polarization are one such orthogonal pair. LHCP and RHCP are another such pair. It is sometimes useful to use superposition to analyze a problem, but when you use superposition to say "ah ha! all polarizations are present so it doesn't matter what antenna I pick!" you are making an error.

Comment: So if you simply say "they don't exist because they sum to a linear one" then you're really saying that *no* two polarizations can exist at the same time.

Comment: @user253751 If you have a circularly polarized antenna that it could be convenient to consider everything as a superposition of RHCP and LHCP. Now _if_ everything you received consisted of both RHCP and LHCP in equal amplitude, you could conclude your antenna would always receive half the power. But what you are missing is this is _not_ the case on an ionospheric channel: sometimes all the power will be in the RHCP component, other times all in the LHCP component. This means sometimes your antenna will receive all the power, and other times none of it. It is no different than a linear antenna.

Comment: @user253751 yes, that is what I'm saying, and you can also see it in Marcus Müller's answer below: "any wave can only occupy *one* point in polarization space." Now you can use superposition to divide that one point into two orthogonal components, but you _must then consider both components throughout the analysis_. This is the part you seem to be missing: if you erect a LHCP receive antenna then you must also consider what happens to the RHCP portion of the signal: _you don't receive it at all_. That is, you get polarization fading.

Comment: The question was: does a linearly polarized signal have both circularly polarized components? How does this make sense? And the answer is: yes, because the linearly polarized signal can be decomposed like this.

Comment: @user253751 that's certainly one way to think of it, but that does not then mean a circularly polarized antenna is immune to polarization fading on ionospheric channels [as you are claiming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/long-range-hf-polarization/16883?noredirect=1#comment27608_16883).

Comment: @PhilFrost Superposition is a mathematical model that helps understanding how these things work, but it doesn't fully represent the realty of how the waves actually propagate.  Your model is incomplete and therefore flawed, and your understanding how these waves work in reality is incorrect.

Comment: @user10489 I find it a little odd your are questioning the validity of superposition when you've written several times about how Faraday rotation involves splitting the wave into RHCP and LHCP components. That "splitting" you keep mentioning: that's superposition in action.

Comment: I have no problem with superposition, when it is used correctly.